# Не работает "Jump to definition" в XCode

Tags: xcode, config, project

Нужно разобраться в большом проекте, основная часть которого написана на Objective-C. В **XCode 11.6** создал проект *"Cross-platform -> External build system*" и добавил существующие файлы. Быстрая навигация по прокету не работает - "Jump to definition" не показывает ни определений функций, ни макросов, ни даже файлы, прописанные в `#import`/`#include` не открывает по cmd+click (даже системные инклуды).

С XCode раньше не работал, так как пишу под линукс в осноновном. Подскажите пожалуйста как настроить проект, чтобы работала быстрая навигация?

Comment: Как добавляли? Почему именно "Cross-platform -> External build system"?

Comment: @VAndrJ, выкачал из гитлаба, создал проект Cross-platform и накидал туда файлов в надежде, что XCode это всё проанализирует. В проекте нет нормального Makefile, вместо него используется питонский scons. Например в линуксе при создании проекта из этих исходников NetBeans всё автоматически выстраивает и парсит SCons-скрипты, но к сожалению не знает что делать с Objective-C и его Foundation-ами, и функционал быстрой навигации соответственно ограничен. Неужели XCode "тупее" NetBeans-а в плане парсинга исходников?

Comment: Думаю, Вам нужно пойти от обратного. Не создавать проект и подбрасывать туда файлы, а из файлов сгенерировать проект. Что в SConstruct этого проекта?

Comment: @VAndrJ, в SConstruct прописаны import-ы проектных файлов для каждого модуля проекта, а также прочая питонская писанина по сборке.

Comment: Что-то про XcodeProject есть в нем?

Comment: @VAndrJ нет, он как кросс-платформенный оформлен, но почему-то на Обджективе. Я установил GNUStep в линукс, и заменил в проекте все `#import` на `#include`, чтобы внутри проекта можно было переходить по файлам Foundation, но к сожалению в самом Foundation используются #import (как-то неправильно и там менять). Может есть IDE под линукс, которые "понимают" #import-ы также как и #include, и показывают декларированные в файлах по этим путям объекты? Мне чисто разобраться что к чему не grep-ая, так как проект достаточно большой и с кучей связей, и переписать потом на нормальный язык